# Send batch messages to Service Bus topic from Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, servicebus

In Azure function I am using service bus trigger to read message from queue and send it to a topic after processing the message. I am using `return` output binding option to send message. This works as expected.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
    [return: ServiceBus("mytopic", EntityType.Topic, Connection = "topicConnection")]
    public static async Task<Message> Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "queueconnection")] Message myQueueItem, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, ILogger log)
```

But now I am planning to read messages from a queue as batch. So to achieve this I am using `Message[] myQueueItem` which works.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
    [return: ServiceBus("mytopic", EntityType.Topic, Connection = "topicConnection")]
    public static async Task<Message> Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "queueconnection")] Message[] myQueueItem, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, ILogger log)
```

But I am not finding any option to send messages to topic as batch or array of messages using the `return` option. One of the alternative option is to use TopicClient object and call SendBatchAsync. I want to understand if I can do this using the `return` option easily.

Answer (score 3):

When sending multiple messages with Functions, depending on the SDK you're using the implementation is different. For In-Process SDK you use a collector. For Isolated Worker SDK you use a custom returned type. I have a [blog post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/functions-isolated-worker-sending-multiple-messages) that goes into details for both SDKs.